# How to identify the first text in a cell as a number or text and swap them in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a cell containing the following text: B 624. i need to swap the text to:  624 B. There are many instances where this occurs, some with other text like: E 625 that i also need to swap.

Comment: is there always a space in there ?

Comment: How many different cases you need to replace?

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,9999) & " " & LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

This assume that there are two parts separated by a single space.